# Yii relation through error is ambiguos

Tags: activerecord, yii

i have a structure in mysql:

```
community:
id | etc...

category:
id | community_id | etc

topic:
id | category_id | etc
```

So, i'm write relations in Community model

```
'categories' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Category', 'community_id'],
'topics' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Topic', 'id', 'through' => 'categories'],
```

But, relation topics not work, error: Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Your relations should be like this:

```
'categories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Category', 'community_id'),
'topics' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Topic', array('category_id','id'), 'through' => 'categories'),
```